# React native. Где сохранять данные?

Tags: база-данных, reactjs, native

например, если у меня есть React native приложение, в котором пользователь вводит что-то и это выводится. При перезапуске приложения выведенные данные пропадут. Как сделать чтобы они сохранились? Какие есть решения? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать local storage или secure storage например

Answer (score 0):

В React Native есть хранилище аналогичное localStorage в браузере

https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install

```
const storeData = async (value) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', value)
  } catch (e) {
    // saving error
  }
}

const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
    if(value !== null) {
      // value previously stored
    }
  } catch(e) {
    // error reading value
  }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]